# Add wysiwyg to zend framework 3

Tags: wysiwyg, zend-framework3

I try add wysiwyg tinymce to my Zend Framework 3 application.

Put src folder to **public\js\tinymce**

Include to  **\Post\view\layout\layout.phtml**

```
 `<?= $this->headScript()`
     ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/bootstrap.min.js'))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'))
        ->prependFile($this->basePath('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js'))
    ?>
```

In view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?= $this->formLabel($form->get('text')); ?>
        <br>
        <?= $this->formElement($form->get('text')); ?>
        <?= $this->formElementErrors($form->get('text')); ?>

    </div>
```

But as a result, the editor does not turn on. What have I forgotten?

Comment: You need to do more than just include the TinyMCE javascript file, see the instructions: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/first-steps/

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your view layout just before the end of the head tag

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea', // change this value according to your HTML
            theme: 'modern',
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
                'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
                'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
            ],
            toolbar: [
                'insertfile undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \n\
            bullist numlist outdent indent | formatselect forecolor backcolor emoticons code | table \n\
            nonbreaking template pagebreak | blockquote | link image | print preview media fullpage removeformat'

            ]
        });
    </script>
```